# About vector addition

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm teaching myself vector space and there are some phrase that I can't understand.

About vector addition, the book says,
Either $v$ or $w$ may be applied at $P$ and a vector having the same magnitude and direction as the other may be applied to the endpoint of the first. If this is done, the endpoint of the second vector is the endpoint of $v+w$.

I think it means that if $w$ stays at the same point $P$ and $v$ starts from the endpoint $w$, the length of $v+w$ is still same. But what does "the endpoint of the second vector is the endpoint of $v+w$" means? Since the vector addition in here is represented by the diagonal of parallelogram, I think that sentence is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this means is: You take some point $P$ and draw either $v$ or $w$ with its tail at $P$. Let's say you use $v$. You then take $w$ (if you had used $w$ for the first step, you would now take $v$), and draw it with its tail at $v$'s tip, i.e., you take a vector with the same magnitude and direction as $w$ (this is a fancy way of saying you just take a copy of $w$) and place it where $v$ ends. The vector that goes from $P$ to the tip of the one you just drew is $v+w$.

[image: vector addition]